# Как нормально определять объекты через open cv?

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

У меня проблема в том что объекты находятся раз через раз а то вообще не находятся, можно как то пофиксить?
Мне надо найти вот этот скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на этом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, пытался много раз подобрать threshold не помогло, так же использовал вместо 1 картинки только вырезанный png скрин но он тоже плохо находит, как сделать что бы норм определял такие маленькие объекты?

Comment: попробуйте использовать производные картинки и шаблона, https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html, шаблон уменьшите до рыбы и сделайте фон чёрный